# Getting this Selenium webdriver http error in angular 4 project

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**ERROR** in

```
./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\aprajita.singh\Documents\Angular 4\Auto-Trender-Project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http' 
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\aprajita.singh\Documents\Angular 4\Auto-Trender-Project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http'.
```

Following are my imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http'; 
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable'; 
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you, when you don't give us the code you are working with. Please create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

There's definitely one or more instances in your Angular App where you're importing `Http` from `selenium-webdriver/http` This could be because of using an **AutoImport Plugin**.

Following are the possible imports:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

or

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

or

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. But I am importing the http in service.ts in the same manner as you did but still getting this error.  This is the service.ts file              import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve here? Your imports look redundant. If you're using `HttpClient` then you won't need `Http` and other stuff. Also, there's definitely one instance in your Angular App where you're importing `Http` from `selenium-webdriver\http` This could be because of using an **AutoImport Plugin**.

Comment: Okay. Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HttpModule has been deprecated.
use HttpClientModule instead.

import it after Broswer Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostsComponent } from './posts/posts.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```